# Angular Typescript Create a File object from assets img directory

Tags: angular, image, file, assets, typescript2.0

I'm trying to implement a custom image selection. I want to propose several image in a modal and when a user click on one element, put it in a File object in my ts (like a file picker). I don't want to use a filepicker to restrict image choice.

I load my images like this from assets directory :

```
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of [].constructor(12); let i = index">
        <img (click)="onSelectImage($event)" class="col-4 img-illustration" src="assets/img/illustrations/illustration{{i}}.png" alt="illustration{{i}}">
      </ng-container>
```

I want to create a new File object in my .ts with the src of the selected image to send it to server.

ex :

```
const file = new File(.......)
```

Can I do this ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own function and put it in a service:

```
async convertRelativeUriToFile(filePath: string, fileName: string, mimeType: any) {
    mimeType = mimeType || `image/${filePath.split(".")[filePath.split(".").length - 1]}`;
    const imageUrl = await fetch(filePath);
    const buffer = await imageUrl.arrayBuffer();
    return new File([buffer], fileName, { type: mimeType });
}

const file = await this.convertRelativeUriToFile(<YOUR_FILE_URL>, <YOUR_FILE_NAME>, <YOUR_MIME_TYPE>)
```